# OR operator in Javascript not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a really strange question, but here is my snippet of JS code

```
if ($("#formCountryCode").val() !== "Choose One" || $("#formCountryCode").val() !== "Select One") {
    formCountryCode = $("#formCountryCode").val();
}
```

Basically, when i'm grabbing the value from the form, and I run through the debugger, the value does equal "Choose One", yet it still goes inside the if statement, which is really confusing me.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: When the value is "Choose One", it's not "Select One". So one of the conditions is truthy!

Comment: This problem does not seem to be related to the way JavaScript has implemented the OR operator.

Comment: My god this is embarassing

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the first condition is `false` because the value is "Choose One", the second condition will return `true` because `"Choose One" !== "Select One"`:

```
$("#formCountryCode").val() !== "Select One"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `AND` not `OR`:

```
if ($("#formCountryCode").val() !== "Choose One" && $("#formCountryCode").val() !== "Select One") {
    formCountryCode = $("#formCountryCode").val();
}
```